# How do I see the cost of a specific Dataflow streaming job in GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

I have multiple streaming jobs running in the same project, and the GCP billing page isn't very granular - I'd like to break things out per job. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, the dataflow UI does not provide a per-job breakdown of costs. You can calculate the cost of a job using [Dataflow's pricing rules](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/pricing-model), and multiplying those by the metrics in the **Resource metrics** section of the UI.

[image: Job summary]

Comment: what do you mean by `Resource metrics`? I see the area where I can check each VM instance details, is that it?

Comment: I've added a screenshot of the job summary in the UI. The bottom of the image contains *Resource metrics*, such as Total vCPU time, Total PD Time, and Total memory time; which you can multiply by the dataflow rules to figure out the price of your job.